# Counting sum of difference of values in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a problem with an SQL query ,I have to count the difference between values in every "range" of values during a timeslot. Here is an example of what am I trying to do :

I have a table with two column data and a timestamp

```
Value   Time
5       16:00
6       17:00
7       18:00
0       19:00
1       20:00
2       21:00
3       22:00
4       23:00
5       00:00
6       01:00
0       02:00
...
```

And I have to give as result the sum of the difference of the values on every time slot. So this table will give me the result 8 because you have the difference between 7 and 5 and between 6 and 0.

I had the idea of calculating the sum of these difference of value by analysing each row and changing the min and max value found until I reach 0 then making the difference between them and save the result in a variable that will be additioned until the end of the table using the same logic but I think it is possible to do it with one query and a quite better performance . Could you help me on that case ?

Comment: Specify how to calculate to get 8, with numbers.

Comment: I don't udnerstand your question here. What are causing you to compare  `[Value]` 5 (@ `'16:00'` or `'00:00'`) and `[Value]` 7 (which is only at `'18:00'`). Why do these rows relate?

Comment: Also, what defines the order of your table? We can't order by `[Time]`, as `'02:00'` is before almost every other time in your dataset (yet appears at the end of your sample data), and we can't order by `[value]`, as that changes the order of the dataset as well. How do we return your data from your table in the order you have provided?

Comment: The timestamp is just here to filter the table . the value represent for example the minutes spent during an event and when the target is reached it returns back to 0 .I want to know how much minutes did you spend during a time slot for example between 16:00 and 02:00 you have two minutes between 5 and 7 then it turns to 0 and you spend 6 more minutes so 2 minutes + 6 minutes =8 minutes. the time is just the order of every sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very much a stab in the dark, however, it comes with a **big** caveat. You need some kind of Identity Column in your data. At the moment, we cannot order your data in the the order you have provided in your sample data.

Data, in a SQL Server Table, is stored as a HEAP. it has **NO** order. When you run a `SELECT * FROM [Table];` the data will be returned from the Server in whatever order it "feels like". It might be be in the order you inserted it in (if it's a small table), however, it's never guaranteed. It might, also be in the order of your `CLUSTERED INDEX`, however, again it's never guaranteed. This becomes especially more common that it isn't when you have larger tables, and multiple cores are using to run the same query.

With your data, ordering is vital to the answer to your question. If we can't achieve the order in your your sample data by using that data, then your goal is unachievable.

Thus, for this, I have **had** to add an additional column to the table. This may well mean that you cannot back date this, as there's n way we could guarantee that a `IDENTITY` column would populate in the right order.

Anyway, onto the solution. This is just one idea, and relies on you using SQL Server 2012 onwards (and having that `IDENTITY` column I was talking about). If you can't change the DDL of your table, however, then you cannot achieve your goal; simply said.

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE #Test (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), --Note I have had to add an IDENTITY Column
                                          --Without this, your goal is not possible, as 
                                          --your ordering cannot be maintained.
                    [Value] int, [Time] time);

INSERT INTO #Test ([Value], [Time])
VALUES (5,'16:00'),
       (6,'17:00'),
       (7,'18:00'),
       (0,'19:00'),
       (1,'20:00'),
       (2,'21:00'),
       (3,'22:00'),
       (4,'23:00'),
       (5,'00:00'),
       (6,'01:00'),
       (0,'02:00');

WITH Groups AS(
    SELECT *,
           COUNT(CASE [Value] WHEN 0 THEN 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM #Test),
FirstLast AS(
    SELECT FIRST_VALUE([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY ID) AS FirstValue,
           LAST_VALUE([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS LastValue,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY ID) AS RN
    FROM Groups)
SELECT SUM(LastValue - FirstValue) AS TotalDifference
FROM FirstLast
WHERE RN = 1;

DROP TABLE #Test;
```

Comment: Hello , first thank you for your answer . I think it is pretty what I am looking for but it keeps telling me that the multipart identifier  could not be bound .

Comment: Can you supply the full error, please, @user2493388 ?

Comment: Actualy the problem was created by an inner join that I have to make in order to filter the sample data by time ( I had to make the desciption of the problem more simple but the mecanism remains the same :) ) . The problem is solved !! Really thank you :)